# When i click NO or CANCEL in MsgBox, i get run time 1004 error in Excel VBA whie saving

Tags: vba

I have a VBA macro code to SAVE AS an Excel Invoice using a button. Whenever I click "YES", the file is saved again. But when I click "NO", "CANCEL" or even CLOSE the MSgBox window, I Get Run-time error '1004', Cannot access 'filename.xlsm'.

```
Sub Save_As()
Dim filename As String
Dim msgResponse As VbMsgBoxResult
filename = "C:\Users\bala\Desktop\SDH\Excel Invoice\" & Range("F4") & Range("G4") & "_" & Range("M10")
If Len(Dir(filename)) = 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.SaveAs filename, FileFormat:=52, CreateBackup:=True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    MsgBox "Invoice saved successully", vbOKOnly, "INVOICE SAVED"
Else
   msgResponse = MsgBox("Do you want to overwrite?", vbYesNoCancel)
   If msgResponse = vbYes Then
        ActiveSheet.SaveAs filename, FileFormat:=52, CreateBackup:=True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        MsgBox "Invoice saved successully", vbOKOnly, "INVOICE SAVED"
   Else
       Exit Sub
    End If
End If
```

End Sub

[image]

Comment: After saving the file you should close it. So you can avoid that error. Close file like this `ActiveWorkbook.Close`

Comment: Where should this be included? is it ActiveWorkbook.Close = True

Comment: You can place it after `MsgBox "Invoice saved successully", vbOKOnly, "INVOICE SAVED"` and Just put `ActiveWorkbook.Close` no need = True

Comment: done. Still the same.

Answer (score 2):

You should always check the response to user input, in this case what button was pressed.

```
Dim msgResponse As VbMsgBoxResult
msgResponse = MsgBox("Do you want to overwrite?", vbYesNoCancel)

If msgResponse = vbYes Then
    ' Overwrite file
Else
    ' Don't
End If
```

Comment: i have edited the code now, as per both the response, Kindly let me know what is the error still. check the code in the question

Comment: Can you post more of your code? What line are you getting the error at? There is no reason for the code to crash when pressed 'Cancel' with the code you are showing.

Comment: Hi all, I have updated the code in the question. Any error handler to be used?